# How can I avoid the wrong situation that happens when creating a jsonl type file while handling concurrency?

Tags: go, web-crawler, nested-loops, goroutine

Crawling is in progress using golang, and at this time, channels are also used to exchange data. However, when I run this code, The speed has definitely increased, but when I try to create a jsonl-type file while processing it with concurrency, a situation such as two line breaks or two consecutive writes occurs. What should I do to prevent this situation?

```
package next

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type IApi struct {
    Tree []ITree `json:"tree"`
}

type ITree struct {
    CodeTitle  string `json:"code_title"`
    Degree     string `json:"degree"`
    EngText    string `json:"eng_text"`
    GubunCode  string `json:"gubun_code"`
    KorText    string `json:"kor_text"`
    LastNodeAt string `json:"last_node_at"`
    LevelNo    int    `json:"level_no"`
    LevelTitle string `json:"level_title"`
}

func Main() {
    KCD_numbers := []int{5, 6, 7, 8}
    c := make(chan IApi)
    c1 := make(chan IApi)
    c2 := make(chan IApi)
    c3 := make(chan IApi)
    f, _ := os.OpenFile("./koicd_code_list.json", os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, fs.FileMode(0644))
    for _, KCD_NO := range KCD_numbers {
        go kcdLoop(KCD_NO, c, f)
    }
    for _, KCD_NO := range KCD_numbers {
        api_url := fmt.Sprintf("https://www.koicd.kr/kcd/0%s/kcd.tree.json", strconv.Itoa(KCD_NO))
        k1_list := (<-c).Tree
        for _, k1 := range k1_list {
            go kcdLoop1(k1, c1, api_url, f)
        }
        for i := 0; i < len(k1_list); i++ {
            k2_list := (<-c1).Tree
            for _, k2 := range k2_list {
                go kcdLoop2(k2, c2, api_url, f)
            }
            for j := 0; j < len(k2_list); j++ {
                k3_list := (<-c2).Tree
                for _, k3 := range k3_list {
                    go kcdLoop3(k3, c3, api_url, f)
                }
                for k := 0; k < len(k3_list); k++ {
                    k4_list := (<-c3).Tree
                    for _, k4 := range k4_list {
                        w1, _ := json.Marshal(k4)
                        f.Write([]byte("\n"))
                        f.Write(w1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    f.Close()
}

func kcdLoop(KCD_NO int, c chan IApi, f *os.File) {
    api_url := fmt.Sprintf("https://www.koicd.kr/kcd/0%s/kcd.tree.json", strconv.Itoa(KCD_NO))
    resp, herr := http.PostForm(api_url, url.Values{})
    if herr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error making http request: %s\n", herr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var res IApi
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&res)
    c <- res
}

func kcdLoop1(k1 ITree, c1 chan IApi, api_url string, f *os.File) {
    k1_resp, k1_herr := http.PostForm(api_url, url.Values{"level_no": {strconv.Itoa(k1.LevelNo)}, "level_title": {k1.LevelTitle}})
    if k1_herr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error making http request: %s\n", k1_herr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var k1_res IApi
    json.NewDecoder(k1_resp.Body).Decode(&k1_res)
    c1 <- k1_res
}

func kcdLoop2(k2 ITree, c2 chan IApi, api_url string, f *os.File) {
    k2_resp, k2_herr := http.PostForm(api_url, url.Values{"level_no": {strconv.Itoa(k2.LevelNo)}, "level_title": {k2.LevelTitle}})
    if k2_herr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error making http request: %s\n", k2_herr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var k2_res IApi
    json.NewDecoder(k2_resp.Body).Decode(&k2_res)
    c2 <- k2_res
}

func kcdLoop3(k3 ITree, c3 chan IApi, api_url string, f *os.File) {
    w, _ := json.Marshal(k3)
    f.Write([]byte("\n"))
    f.Write(w)
    k3_resp, k3_herr := http.PostForm(api_url, url.Values{"level_no": {strconv.Itoa(k3.LevelNo)}, "level_title": {k3.LevelTitle}})
    if k3_herr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error making http request: %s\n", k3_herr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var k3_res IApi
    json.NewDecoder(k3_resp.Body).Decode(&k3_res)
    c3 <- k3_res
}
```

The speed has definitely increased, but when I try to create a jsonl-type file while processing it with concurrency, a situation such as two line breaks or two consecutive writes occurs. What should I do to prevent this situation?